# Trie data structure implementaion's bug

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, trie

what is the bug in the searching function

```
search_word();
```

and is this implementation uses the efficiency time complexity for the Trie or not for operations like insertion / searching.
consider a string of 1500 letter performing the insertions/searching operation in time less than 2 seconds , can it be passed ?

```
    class Trie
{
private:
     struct node
    {
        bool isWord;
        node* child[26];
        node()
        {
            for(int i = 0;i < 26;i++)
                child[i] = NULL;
            isWord = false;
        }
    };

    void insert_word(int index, node* vertex, int i, string s)
    {
        if(index == SZ)
        {
            vertex -> isWord = true;
             return;
        }
        int c = s[index] - 'a';
        if(vertex -> child[c] == NULL)
            vertex -> child[c] = new node;

        insert_word(index + 1, vertex -> child[c], c, s);

    }
    bool search_word(int index, node* vertex, int i, string s)
    {
        if(index == SZ && vertex -> isWord == true)
            return true;
        if(index == SZ && vertex -> isWord == false)
            return false;

        int c = s[index] - 'a';

        if(vertex -> child[c] == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            return search_word(index + 1, vertex -> child[c], c, s);
    }
public:
    int SZ;
    node* root;
    Trie()
    {
        root = new node;
    }
    void insert_word(string s)
    {
        SZ = s.size();
        insert_word(0, root, s[0] - 'a', s);
    }
    bool search_word(string s)
    {
        SZ = s.size();
      return search_word(0, root, s[0] - 'a', s);
    }

};
```

update : found the bug and the code must work correctly .

Answer (score 1):

well, i have found the bug and it is in the code block

```
  if(index == (SZ - 1))
    {
        vertex -> isWord = true;
         return;
    }
```

index must be checked for == with size itself not size-1 why.. ?
ex: string ab if we are now processing at the letter b is it == to size - 1 meaning last character in the string the code will mark it's root as end of word not the node related to the character b because it had never been created
by editing it to size it should working properly also in

```
search_word()
```

the size - 1 must be edited too

note : i will update the question itself to have the fixed code.